# Echoed data from a MySQL database field is '1' but the value is actually '0'?

Tags: php, mysql, echo

Simply put I have a MySQL database, I've got a table with a 'tinyINT' field.
I'm echoing the values of each entry's tinyINT field and they're all working fine.

If the value in the field is 1+ it prints to the page as expected, but if I change any value to 0, PHP prints a 1 - but a double check through phpmyadmin reveals that the field still contains a 0.

I've tried changing the datatype to decimal/real/INT/smallINT - and none of that seems to solve the problem.

I'm presuming it's something embarrassingly simple that I'm overlooking, but at the moment I'm completely stumped!

Any ideas? :/

```
   $sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5";
   $query = mysqli_query($con, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error($con));
        $query_result = mysqli_num_rows($query); 
        if ($query_result == 0) {
            echo "no matches";
        }
        else {
            // Output the data using a while loop 
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {  
                // Gather all $row values into local variables 
                $value= $row["int_field"];
                                echo $value;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Could you add the PHP code to your question, please?

Comment: show your code, please (oops. i'm not the 1st one)

Comment: SOLVED! I'd missed out a double comparison operator '==' and had a single one earlier in the code, that was running through and causing issues. Sorry and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! I'd missed out a double comparison operator '==' and had a single one earlier in the code, that was running through and causing issues.